# Expanding $\| \vec{e}_n\|_2$ in $\ell_2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces, notation

During my lecture today for my *introduction to metric spaces* class, we considered the sequence of vectors: $\{\vec{e}_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ $\in \ell_2$ such that $$\begin{align*} \vec{e}_1 & = (1,0,0,0,\ldots) \\ \vec{e}_2 & = (0,1,0,0,\ldots) \\ \vec{e}_3 & = (0,0,1,0,0,\ldots) \\ & \,\,\, \vdots  \end{align*}$$
We know that this sequence converges coordinate wise, but the sequence is not convergent to $\vec{0}$. However, I started to write out (since my lecturer omitted to) $$\| \vec{e}_n - \vec{0}\|_2 = \left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\color{red}{\cdots} )^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and realized, I had no idea how to write the summand (the $\color{red}{red}$ dots) respecting the appropriate indexing. Since each $n$ is a vector with an infinite number of components, what would the notation be for this inside the sum? However, the point of this computation is to show that $\| \vec{e}_n - \vec{0}\| = \|\vec{e}_n\| = 1$, $\forall n$. Which he explained during lecture, but I wanted to see for myself and expand out this notation.

My thoughts were following along the lines of how we add vectors: such that the summand is the square of the $m^\text{th}$ component of the $n^\text{th}$ unit vector: $$\| \vec{e}_n - \vec{0}\|_2 = \| \vec{e}_n\|_2 = \left( \sum_{n,m = 1}^\infty (e_n^m)^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ However, I am still unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $i$ and $j$ are positive integers, define the number $\delta_{ij}$ by
$$\delta_{ij} := \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } i=j, \\ 0 & \textrm{if } i \neq j. \end{cases}$$
Then the $m$-th component of $\vec e_n$ is $\delta_{mn}$, right? Now note that, in the sum
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty (\delta_{mn})^2$$
the unique term which is not $0$ is a $1$ when $m=n$. Hence
$$(\|\vec e_n\|_2)^2 = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (\delta_{mn})^2 = 1.$$

Comment: ahhhh the Kronecker delta, thank you! +1 from me.